How to use datafusion to retrieve real-time appended .arrow files
I am using datafusion to retrieve an arrow file appended in real time.
Here is my v1 version:
    #[tokio::test]
    pub async fn arrow_file_search_v1() -> Result<(),Error>{
        // init datafusion context
        let config = SessionConfig::from_env()?
            .with_information_schema(true)
            .with_batch_size(8 * 1024);

        let runtime_env = RuntimeEnv::new(RuntimeConfig::default())?;
        let context = SessionContext::new_with_config_rt(config, Arc::new(runtime_env));
        
        let file_format = ArrowFormat::default();
        let listing_options = ListingOptions::new(Arc::new(file_format)).with_file_extension(FileType::ARROW.get_ext());

        let mut config = ListingTableConfig::new(ListingTableUrl::parse("./1715856177.arrow").unwrap())
            .with_listing_options(listing_options)
            .with_schema(Arc::from(schema()));

        let table = ListingTable::try_new(config)?;
        context.register_table("tbl", Arc::new(table))?;

        // exec query
        let sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl";
        let mut df = match context.sql(sql).await {
            Ok(df) => df,
            _ => return Err(Error::msg("exec sql error")),
        };

        let batches = df.clone().collect().await?;

        Ok(())
    }

The error reported after running:
Error: Arrow error: Parser error: Arrow file does not contain correct footer

Caused by:
    Parser error: Arrow file does not contain correct footer

Guess it's because the arrow file is written in real-time append and the footer information is not written yet
So I wrote the v2 version, which uses StreamReader to stream read the record_batch, and then registers the record_batch to give to datafusion for retrieval
    #[tokio::test]
    pub async fn arrow_file_search_v2() -> Result<(),Error>{
        // init datafusion context
        let config = SessionConfig::from_env()?
            .with_information_schema(true)
            .with_batch_size(8 * 1024);

        let runtime_env = RuntimeEnv::new(RuntimeConfig::default())?;
        let context = SessionContext::new_with_config_rt(config, Arc::new(runtime_env));

        // read record_batch by stream_reader
        let file = File::open("./1715856177.arrow").unwrap();
        let reader = BufReader::new(file);
        
        let mut reader = StreamReader::try_new(reader, None).unwrap();
        let schema_ref = reader.schema();
        
        let mut in_records_batches: Vec<RecordBatch>  = vec![];
        while let Some(batch) = reader.next() {
            in_records_batches.push(batch.unwrap());
        }

        // register table to memtable
        let mem_table = Arc::new(MemTable::try_new(Arc::from(schema_ref), vec![in_records_batches])?);
        context.register_table("tbl", mem_table.clone())?;

        // exec query
        let sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl";
        let mut df = match context.sql(sql).await {
            Ok(df) => df,
            _ => return Err(Error::msg("exec sql error")),
        };

        let batches = df.clone().collect().await?;

        Ok(())
    }

The code ran successfully!
My question is, if I want to retrieve a real-time appended arrow file using datafusion, is there any other better way?
